# Unity: Is there a 2D equivalent to the avatar mask that is used on the animator layers?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, character, 2d

I am creating a 2D game and I want to add a shooting animation to my character.
I want to add it in a different animation layer so it will affect only the upper body part of my character while not breaking the basic movements animations such as idle, run and jump.
In tutorials and guides, I saw the usage of an avatar mask on 3D models.
Is there an option to use that masking on a 2D character?
Thank you :)

Comment: I have found the solution in a video tut here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-3sK-cPIBY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Unity doesn't provide out-of-the-box solutions for 2D [Avatar Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationMaskOnImportedClips.html). One thing you can do to emulate this feature is split you character's body parts (arms, legs, torso, etc) into different animations, then assign each a Layer in the associated [Animator Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AnimatorController.html) and control them programmatically via script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that if I'm making an animation for idle I'll need to do it in 2 layers? one for the upper body  parts and one for the bottom body parts? Is the solution you suggested is a common one in the 2D game developing community?

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Making sure you didn't miss it :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean with splitting your characters body parts. In 2D game development is a common pattern having sprites animations with bones (just like 3D) as it gives move flexibility and reusability over single sprites. Check out [this](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/11/09/getting-started-with-unitys-2d-animation-package/) for more.

Comment: I am using different body part sprites for a single character. I am not sure I understand you entirely. For being able to let's say run and shoot at the same time, I have to create 2 animation layers: one for the bottom part (legs) and one for the upper part (body, head, hands). Then I have to control it by script by making the first animation layer run (with a boolean parameter let's say) and the second animation switch between the running upper body animation to the shooting upper body animation by a trigger parameter? that way I'm mixing between the layers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly, you got the idea.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.